# mantain text when fading out a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am playing with youtube iframe api for video background, what i want to do is, i want to have a background color beofre the video starts and that background color should cover the entire div, plus should also have a text at the center, my problem is related to that text, because when i fade the div with the background color out when the video starts, i want to mantain the text, the text should be always there, how can i do something like that?, i already have my background color div and the video, but i can't mantain the text on the div.

html

```
 <section class="content_section bg_fixed white_section bg2">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
            <div id="over">
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>

                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <div class="title-wrapper main_title text-center centered upper">
                        <h2><span class="line"></span>Simple solutions for complex problems</h2>
                    </div>

                    <div class="description4 centered">
                        <p dir="ltr"><b id="docs-internal-guid-7b963bcb-e991-08ff-b846-612f8d57baee">The world is a complex place.&nbsp;</b><br><b>Our solutions are designed to allow organisations to quickly and simply use their information without adding layers and layers of heavy software.<br>
Usability and simple deployment are the key words.</b></p>

                        <p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>

                        <p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>

                        <p dir="ltr">&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <div id="video_overlays"></div>

            <div class="container" style="position: relative;">


            </div>
            <div id="player" width="100%" height="100%" style="z-index:-1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The transparency of the div affects the transparency of all its children, so when you fade it, anything that's inside fades too. Try to create a separate div that will contain the text and place it in your code below the div with the background color. Then, use relative positioning to put it right over the background.

```js
$('.bg').animate({'opacity': 0}, 2000);
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}

.text {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  top: -200px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg">

</div>
<div class="text">
  Your text here.
</div>
```

Comment: tried that, but the text is not showing up, i think it has something to do with the z-index, since i have a background color div above the video(i set z-index for both) i want my text div to be the upper one, but when i try to put the higher z-index it doesn't work, any tip?

Comment: Both the background and the text have higher z-index than the video? See the snippet I added after I edited the post.